# Using a dropbox-type solution for students where their folders are protected

Tags: dropbox, cloud, cloud-storage, password-protection, sugarsync

I need a solution like dropbox for computers in our lab where students have access to their files. We created an account for our lab on dropbox and so there's a folder now synced on all computers for each student. Problem is students can see and **edit** other students' work.

How can we protect these folders? We could make every student have a dropbox account, login when they get here (*perfectly acceptable*), logout when they leave (*again perfectly acceptable*) and delete their dropbox folder so the next student can login to their dropbox account. I ***know*** this is going to be prone to mistakes and conflicts though.

Sugarsync seems to have an amazing solution for my needs. A pure cloud drive. When you close the Sugarsync application, your drive disappears, because it was always in the cloud. Problem with it is you ***can't log off***! Surprising... but I don't know how yet. Seems like you have to uninstall the app to change accounts? There must be a registry entry or file with the information.

***UPDATE***: I found out you type <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to uninstall Sugarsync. It doesn't really uninstall though, it just quits and when you run it again it asks for new account or user/password. Perfect! Except then you have to say no to upgrading, name the computer, etc... Not very nice, but it'll work if there are no other solutions.

***UPDATE 2***: I should've noted we have Macs and PCs.

Comment: Why do the files have to be in the cloud?  This sounds like it would be handled better with local network shares?

Comment: @ernie - because I want students to access the files at home, school or anywhere else they are. Plus it's easier administration-wise.

Comment: Surely Dropbox is PER WINDOWS ACCOUNT? So that students just log into their Windows account and get logged into their Dropbox automatically. You could then have a central account that shares specific folders with each student as required. You could do the same with Windows SkyDrive.

Comment: @JulianKnight, no, Dropbox is a per _OS_ thing. You cannot have multiple Dropbox accounts running on the same OS. I have to agree that network shares are the way to go here. They can easily be made accessible from wherever the students are through VPN or ssh.

Comment: @terdon: I'm pretty sure this isn't correct. "[Dropbox suggests that one way to work around this is by creating multiple user accounts on your computer, which will allow two installations of Dropbox to run independently of each other. You can then leave one account active but dormant in the background, while its Dropbox continues to sync, or switch back and forth as required](http://www.bit.com.au/Guide/313558,do-you-use-dropbox-here-are-some-clever-tricks.aspx)"

Comment: @JulianKnight Well I'll be... I stand corrected. I remember trying this out a while ago and I couldn't get it to work. I was trying to create a maximum of accounts to get a maximum of free space (not nice, I know). I was using the Linux version though, maybe that's why. Or perhaps they have changed something in the current version.

Comment: Yep, doing further reading, I can see that this *used* to be the case but its fixed. I'll add this as an answer. If you like it, please accept!

Comment: If you need to host, it, then I suggest you look at setting up a **WEBDAV** server.  This has some support in almost every common OS, and is easy to get through firewalls since is really just HTTP with some extra bits.

Comment: why not use USB flash drives?

Comment: @Keltari - we have been using flash drives, but the kids lose them all the time... or forget them.

Comment: To answer @Zoredache's question. WebDAV is great but it does NOT do replication or versioning without further software. Dropbox does it "all-in-one" so is super convenient and reasonably robust. Maybe not terribly secure though!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, although Dropbox *used* only to support a single instance, it is now correctly installed PER WINDOWS USER ACCOUNT as you would expect.

So nothing further is required!

Have a nice day!

Comment: Can I do the same for our Macs?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user but, yes, [I believe so](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/how-to-use-multiple-dropbox-ac-163765) B).

Answer (score 0):

Have all the students make a DropBox account, but do not use the installed client.  Have them use the DropBox web interface.  They can upload and download files from DropBox, just like the client.  You can prevent students from browsing other students files by disabling cookies, requiring them to login in every browser session.  Or just make sure they dont click the "remember me" button on the website.

Comment: That's fine, except students have lots of files.. It's too cumbersome to do this for 100 files they may have worked on while at our center. And then they still have to delete their files when they leave too.

Comment: And not at all needed! ;)